# SAT solver Pseudocode

Tags: pseudocode, sat

I'm trying to solve a 3-SAT-problem, where I get a number of clauses, with 3 literals in each. They are in CNF.

I'm having trouble constructing pseudocode for this. I've figured out that it takes a Boolean formula as input, and that I should solve it using brute force. I also know that it's time complexity is O(2^n) because of 2 possible states for each variable.

Where I have trouble understanding is how we access each variable, since we only get a boolean formula. How do I pick out each variable in every clause to loop over them, how would I do the check and how would I leave some variables unassigned/unassign them?

It doesn't have to be efficient, as I'm just trying to prove a point about the brute force time complexity.

Comment: That's mysterious, what is the input format? DIMACS CNF as usual? An arbitrary boolean formula (then what do you want to do with it, Tseytin transformation or trying to put it into CNF without auxiliary variables?). Not clear

Comment: You should show some effort as currently it's more or less a: i got this task and i want to know how to do this question which are not well-received here. It's also unclear where the problem really lies as there is not much shown. In general: if needed, map your variables to the [0, n) range; initialize some boolean array with size n (all zeros) -> the zeros mean negated literals -> check SAT -> add 1 to your boolean array as you would do in a bitcounter -> check SAT -> add 1 and so on until you checked all ones. Stop with SAT (solution obtained) or result UNSAT (proven by enumeration).

Comment: @harold input can be interpreted as anything that is reasonable.